# Scraping data from a web page

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to  scrape data from the following web page 
https://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scorecard/10711/aus-vs-ind-1st-test-india-in-australia-test-series-2011-12 
I need the scoreboard in a tabular format. Can anyone help me out? I am using python3. I am new to web scraping and not much familiar with the internals of a web page. 
Thanks in advance!

I tried using BeautifulSoup with urllib2, etc, but didnt reach anywhere.

Comment: please [edit] to include your code and explain what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas' `read_html()`. This will return a list of dataframes. What you do with it from there is up to you. You'd probably need to do a little tidying up of the data, but I just dumped them into 1 big table to show you.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://m.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scorecard/10711/aus-vs-ind-1st-test-india-in-australia-test-series-2011-12'
dfs = pd.read_html(url)

result =  pd.concat( [ df for df in dfs ] )
```

**Output:**

```
print (result.to_string())
                      0                     1                     2                     3                     4
0               Batting                     R                     B                    4s                    6s
0              Ed Cowan                    68                   177                     7                     0
1  c M Dhoni b R Ashwin  c M Dhoni b R Ashwin  c M Dhoni b R Ashwin  c M Dhoni b R Ashwin  c M Dhoni b R Ashwin
0          David Warner                    37                    49                     4                     1
1   c M Dhoni b U Yadav   c M Dhoni b U Yadav   c M Dhoni b U Yadav   c M Dhoni b U Yadav   c M Dhoni b U Yadav
0           Shaun Marsh                     0                     6                     0                     0
1   c V Kohli b U Yadav   c V Kohli b U Yadav   c V Kohli b U Yadav   c V Kohli b U Yadav   c V Kohli b U Yadav
0         Ricky Ponting                    62                    94                     6                     0
1  c V Laxman b U Yadav  c V Laxman b U Yadav  c V Laxman b U Yadav  c V Laxman b U Yadav  c V Laxman b U Yadav
0        Michael Clarke                    31                    68                     5                     0
1              b Z Khan              b Z Khan              b Z Khan              b Z Khan              b Z Khan
0        Michael Hussey                     0                     1                     0                     0
1    c M Dhoni b Z Khan    c M Dhoni b Z Khan    c M Dhoni b Z Khan    c M Dhoni b Z Khan    c M Dhoni b Z Khan
0           Brad Haddin                    27                    69                     1                     0
1   c V Sehwag b Z Khan   c V Sehwag b Z Khan   c V Sehwag b Z Khan   c V Sehwag b Z Khan   c V Sehwag b Z Khan
0          Peter Siddle                    41                   100                     4                     0
1    c M Dhoni b Z Khan    c M Dhoni b Z Khan    c M Dhoni b Z Khan    c M Dhoni b Z Khan    c M Dhoni b Z Khan
0       James Pattinson                    18                    54                     2                     0
1               not out               not out               not out               not out               not out
0        Ben Hilfenhaus                    19                    32                     3                     0
1  c V Kohli b R Ashwin  c V Kohli b R Ashwin  c V Kohli b R Ashwin  c V Kohli b R Ashwin  c V Kohli b R Ashwin
0           Nathan Lyon                     6                    11                     1                     0
1            b R Ashwin            b R Ashwin            b R Ashwin            b R Ashwin            b R Ashwin
0                Bowler                     O                     M                     R                     W
1           Zaheer Khan                    31                     6                    77                     4
2         Ishant Sharma                    24                     7                    48                     0
3           Umesh Yadav                    26                     5                   106                     3
4   Ravichandran Ashwin                    29                     3                    81                     3
0                  Home           Live Scores                   NaN                   NaN                   NaN
1              Schedule                  News                   NaN                   NaN                   NaN
2            Editorials                Photos                   NaN                   NaN                   NaN
3              Archives               Players                   NaN                   NaN                   NaN
4              Rankings                Series                   NaN                   NaN                   NaN
5                  Poll                Videos                   NaN                   NaN                   NaN
6          Points Table            Contact Us                   NaN                   NaN                   NaN
7       Cricbuzz TV Ads    Careers @ Cricbuzz                   NaN                   NaN                   NaN
8           Mobile Apps    This day that year                   NaN                   NaN                   NaN
9          Wickets Zone                   NaN                   NaN                   NaN                   NaN
0           Mobile Apps       Social Channels                   NaN                   NaN                   NaN
1                iPhone              facebook                   NaN                   NaN                   NaN
2               Android               twitter                   NaN                   NaN                   NaN
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much ! Pandas make things so easy, let me explore that too, however, the following code worked for me:-   request = requests.get(score)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'html.parser') 
  ids = ["innings_1","innings_2","innings_3","innings_4"]    //these were the div IDs which i was looking for
  for id in ids:
   s = soup.find(id=id)
   if s is not None:
    text = s.get_text(separator='')       #and then parse the text (it was similar lines as you got above )

Comment: ya. Pandas uses beautifulsoup under the hood. It just really comes down to what you need. In this particular case, it might be more work to use pandas and then to clean up the table, versus parsing straight from beautifulsoup the way you just described. Sort of like the analogy of trying to crack a nut with a sledge hammer. Will it get the job done? Sure!. Is it the most efficient? Not always. But good to know you have that tool in case for other sites.